# "Invalid object name 'OpenIddictAuthorizations'." - OpenIddict/.Net Core Identity Error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I am new to .Net Core 2.0 and Identity framework. I am trying to use OpenIddict in the project.
References: 
OpenIddict (2.0.0-rc1-final)
OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore(2.0.0-rc1-final)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (2.0.1)
I keep on getting the following runtime error:
**Invalid object name 'OpenIddictAuthorizations'.**

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__108_0(Task`1 result)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
```

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
```

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
```

It looks like a SQL exception but I am not sure why it is looking for an object called OpenIddictAuthorizations in the database. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need this Table in your Db beside other tables

```
dbo.OpenIddictApplications
dbo.OpenIddictAuthorizations
dbo.OpenIddictScopes
dbo.OpenIddictTokens
```

So, OpenId can store the tokens and verify them.

Comment: That it. Thanks ! I created all the tables manually from a template solution instead of migration and completely overlooked these tables. Sorry for the trivial nature of the query. OpenIddict support is somewhat rare as of now. Thanks again for the prompt reply.

Comment: Is there an SQL Server script to manually add those OpenIddict tables?